# Android WebView on a single .html file gives “net::ERR_CACHE_MISS”

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I have created a file on my Android tablet, named "website.html".

It's supposed to create a working iframe of a certain website. The following is the code:

```
<html>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
</html>
```

However, An iframe error always occurs:

```
Website not available

The website [websiteurl] could not be loaded because
net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

**I have seen some answers that require changing the contents of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, however, there is no such file on my device since it's a single html file and not a Android Studio app, etc. Correct me if I'm wrong - but don't those answers only apply to android apps with iframes or web applications, not a single html file.**

Could someone help me with this error? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: My parents did not want me to use a browser, so they change my device configurations somehow such that iframes don't work. Is there a way to change it back? (This is for educational purposes)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest listening to your parents, they want what's best for you. How about you helping someone on here with a project instead?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but not answering the question.